# GraphQL queries via Apollo

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, graphql-java

Hi I'm working on an Android app and I need to use GraphQL. I'm trying to use the Apollo client first by [following this tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/) as practice but am having trouble following it through. It just lacks some specific information and details that would be helpful.

Currently what I'm stuck at is trying to construct a .graphql file. I was hoping to at least compile the code and make sure everything up to this point was fine, but apparently you can't even compile it without providing at least one .graphql file.

I've included the example given in the tutorial below, my confusion mainly comes from what exactly is "FeedQuery" and "FeedType"? Are they classes defined for this particular example or are they classes generated by Apollo itself to define any query? So should I just use those two classes when defining my own queries or make equivalents? And are those parameters also something required in the defintion or something specific to the examples strucutre?

I can't seem to find more information about this in their tutorial or website. It's tough enough trying to learn GraphQL but the lack of details in this tutorial is making things a lot more frustrating. If they had shared what the structure looks like in this tutorial it would have been really helpful but it doesn't seem to be included.

```
query FeedQuery($type: FeedType!, $limit: Int!) {
  feedEntries: feed(type: $type, limit: $limit) {
    id
    repository {
      name
    }
    postedBy {
      login
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help, and if anyone has a link to a better tutorial I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the context of the GraphQL DSL, FeedQuery is a named query (think of it as a method in Java terms) that you can use to retrieve specific data (as described by the internals of the query) from a GraphQL server.

To retrieve the desired data, you need to pass in two non-null arguments (denoted by the `!`), the feedType and the limit. The first is a custom type defined  by the GraphQL schema implemented by the server. The second is a GraphQL scalar type.

Both the FeedQuery and FeedType will be converted to Java objects during compilation phase. For queries, you will be provided with an appropriate builder to include all the necessary information to perform the actual call.

You can read a complete Java example [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/tree/master/apollo-sample). It is a more complete version of the tutorial you are following.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! If you could assist a bit more, how does this query defined in Java in Android Studio relate to the query defined in the schema of the GraphlQL server? For instance, would the server have a query defined as "FeedQuery" or as "feed" or "feedEntries"? And if I tried to define a query in Java that doesn't exist in the GraphQL schema, then that would result in some sort of error right? Thanks again, your answer has helped clear somethings up for me!

Comment: Essentially I'm a bit confused by the difference between "query FeedQuery($type: FeedType!, $limit: Int!)" and "feedEntries: feed(type: $type, limit: $limit)". Like in terms of how they relate to each other and to the query defined in the GraphQL schema.

Comment: The query is something that you create yourself. It has to abide by the GraphQL schema and the DSL language rules. Then during the compilation phase, the GraphQL queries you define are transformed into Java code. Of course if there is an error in your DSL, a compilation error will be thrown. The FeedQuery will be defined by you (you will described what data you want the server returned). The feedEntries part is a query defined by the server to return specific data (much like a specific REST call). Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Right so "FeedQuery" is defined for use in Java, and though we're free to name it whatever we want and can vary what data it requests, it must correspond to a query defined in the GraphQL schema and that query (the one defined in the schema itself) in this case is "feedEntries: feed(...)". Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Yes, though technically not solely for use by Java (although in this case it is, since it is a Java project). You could reuse the same query for example in your iOS application.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with a specific DSL convention naming. However, feed is defined in the corresponding schema.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you so much for all your help! ---And sorry one last question, in the DSL convention it seems like the format is "variableOrFunctionName: variableOrFunctionType". So when we have "feedEntries: feed(type: $type, limit: $limit)" shouldn't it be reversed? Like "feed( type: $type, limit: $limit): feedEntries"? So feedEntries would be a defined type in the schema while feed(....) would be a defined query?---